# Combine multiple APIs with the same array path

Tags: javascript, html, api, vue.js, axios

Using VUE and Axios I am attempting to pull data from Blizzards API server - I want to get the data from different game regions. The code I am using loads the data from both regions, but only puts one set in my table.

My VUE

```
const vm = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    ladderTeams: [],


},
mounted() {
    this.pullGMS();
},
methods: {

    async pullGMS() {

        axios.all([
            axios.get('https://us.api.blizzard.com/sc2/ladder/grandmaster/1?access_token='),
            axios.get('https://us.api.blizzard.com/sc2/ladder/grandmaster/2?access_token=')
        ])
            .then(axios.spread((responseNA, responseKR) => {
                this.ladderTeams = responseNA.data.ladderTeams;
                this.ladderTeams = responseKR.data.ladderTeams;

                console.log(this.ladderTeams = responseNA.data.ladderTeams);
                console.log(this.ladderTeams = responseKR.data.ladderTeams);
            }))
    },
},
```

My HTML

```
<div class="content">
<div style="height:400px;overflow:auto;position:relative;top:40px;" class="table" id="app">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Clan</th>
            <th>Player Name</th>
            <th>Race</th>
            <th>MMR</th>
        </tr>
        <tr v-for="(ladder, teamMembers, displayName, mmr) in ladderTeams">
            <td>{{ ladder.teamMembers[0].clanTag }}</td>
            <td>{{ ladder.teamMembers[0].displayName }}</td>
            <td>{{ ladder.teamMembers[0].favoriteRace }}</td>
            <td>{{ ladder.mmr }}</td>

        </tr>

        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

It does load all of the info from the second API just fine, but not the first - if I comment the second "this" code however - the first loads - so I know it works too, I am just obviously doing something wrong here.

Comment: try this .. `var x = {}; x.a = 1; x.a = 2; console.log(x.a);` - does it surprise you that he output is only `2`? If not, then you should be able to see the problem immediately

Comment: is `response??.data.ladderTeams` an array? if so ... `this.ladderTeams = [... responseNA.data.ladderTeams, ...responseKR.data.ladderTeams];` will fix you - otherwise `this.ladderTeams = Object.assign({}, responseNA.data.ladderTeams, responseKR.data.ladderTeams);` could do the trick

Comment: @JaromandaX - It does not surprise me, and it makes sense when you position it that way. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the arrays to the original variable and replacing them.

Offending Code:

```
this.ladderTeams = responseNA.data.ladderTeams;
this.ladderTeams = responseKR.data.ladderTeams;
```

Correct Code:

```
this.ladderTeams.push(responseNA.data.ladderTeams)
this.ladderTeams.push(responseKR.data.ladderTeams)
```

You are currently doing:

```
let myArray = []
myArray = [1, 2, 3]
myArray = [4, 5, 6]
console.log(myArray) //[4, 5, 6]
```

You need to use `push` to add to the array.

```
let myArray = []
myArray.push([1, 2, 3])
myArray.push([4, 5, 6])
console.log(myArray) //[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
```

Also, regarding `axios.all`, you should substitute with `Promise.all`, which is used under the hood. This Axios version may be deprecated or removed.
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1042

Comment: Thanks. It's obvious when you explain it that way, but I'm still learning. This did work, and I've switched to Promise.all - Everything is good there, but it did break my v-for table. I can load the data, but it's only loading the initial Array - **{{ ladder.ladderTeams[0].teamMembers[0].displayName }}** is actually only pulling in the first name from each array instead of making an entire list of all names.

Comment: That's because your v-for is referring to the array, which is an array of arrays. You'd be better off doing a v-for x in ladderTeams[0] then another for [1] right now. When you get more comfortable with coding in general, you can actually combine them into a single v-for, but do what works for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

```
const vm = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    ladderTeams: [],


},
mounted() {
    this.pullGMS();
},
methods: {

    async pullGMS() {

        axios.all([
            axios.get('https://us.api.blizzard.com/sc2/ladder/grandmaster/1?access_token='),
            axios.get('https://us.api.blizzard.com/sc2/ladder/grandmaster/2?access_token=')
        ])
            .then(axios.spread((responseNA, responseKR) => {
                this.ladderTeams.push(responseNA.data.ladderTeams);
                this.ladderTeams.push(responseKR.data.ladderTeams);

                console.log(this.ladderTeams)
            }))

     },
    }
```